# Random functions and neuronal network

Tags: functional-analysis, brownian-motion, density-function, random-functions, dense-subspaces

Let f be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and B_t a brownian motion.

Is there any density result of the neuronal network class for function of the form $t \mapsto f(B_t)$ ?